# How do I rescue from a `require': no such file to load in ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception, require

I am trying to rescue from a ``require': no such file to load in ruby` in order
to hint the user at specifying the -I flag in case he has forgotten to do so.
Basically the code looks like:

```
begin
  require 'someFile.rb'
rescue
  puts "someFile.rb was not found, have you"
  puts "forgotten to specify the -I flag?"
  exit
end
```

I have expected the `rescue` part to take over execution in case `someFile.rb` was not found, but my assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**rescue** without arguments rescues only *StandardError* s. The *LoadError* (that is raised by a file not found) is not a *StandardError* but a *ScriptError* (see http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/09/06/rubys-exception-hierarchy). Therefore you have to rescue the *LoadError* explicitly, as MBO indicated.

Answer (score 61):

You have to explicitly define which error you want to rescue from.

```
begin
  require 'someFile.rb'
rescue LoadError
  puts "someFile.rb was not found, have you"
  puts "forgotten to specify the -I flag?"
  exit
end
```