# Why is this line raising `cannot load such file` when it should be rescued?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to add puffing-billy to a Rails app by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy).

Running the test suite raises:

```
in `require': cannot load such file -- capybara/webkit (LoadError)
```

I am using Poltergeist not Webkit, and so don't need to load this file.

The error originates from the following line in puffing-billy

```
# /lib/billy/browsers/capybara.rb 

DRIVERS = {
  poltergeist: 'capybara/poltergeist',
  webkit: 'capybara/webkit',
  selenium: 'selenium/webdriver'
}

def self.register_drivers
  DRIVERS.each do |name, driver|
    require driver rescue next # this line should be rescued
    send("register_#{name}_driver")
  end
end
```

What could prevent `require driver` from being rescued and cause this error, and what is a methodical approach to debug this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I rescue from a \`require': no such file to load in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460891/how-do-i-rescue-from-a-require-no-such-file-to-load-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

In general it's a bad idea to use an inline rescuse in Ruby (having rescue be at the end of the line).  Here is a nice article w/ more details: https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2015/09/23/dont-inline-rescue-in-ruby/

Inline rescue and a "unfiltered" rescue (without specifying the type of error you want caught) both catch any exceptions that inherit from `StandardError`  `LoadError` is **not** a descendant of `StandardError` so it's is not caught by your inline rescue.

Here is a chart of error hierarchy in Ruby:
http://blog.honeybadger.io/understanding-the-ruby-exception-hierarchy/

So here is your code modified so it will work and also not catch unintentional errors:

```
DRIVERS.each do |name, driver|
  begin
    require driver
    send("register_#{name}_driver")
  rescue LoadError
    # This skips to the next driver
    # It would be nice to add logging here to notify that the driver was skipped
  end
end
```