# How to rescue from incompatible library version ... (fatal) in ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

I require a native extension, that is in my filesystem but not compatible with my current system. In this case I want to react in ruby and use a mock implementation, but this code

```
begin
  require 'dotstar'
rescue LoadError
  puts "Got LoadError"
  require 'dotstarsimulator'
rescue
  puts "Warning: could not open dotstar native support => using sim"
  require 'dotstarsimulator'
end
```

simply crashes without calling my rescue code.

Same for an irb session, in which I just try to `require 'dotstar'`.

Comment: This behavior is observed in OS X.

Comment: Your question is unclear: You can only `rescue` an `Exception` that is `raise`d. If it "simply crashes", then you cannot `rescue` from it. If it `raise`s an `Exception`, then you can `rescue` from that `Exception`.

Comment: After looking into the ruby mri sourcecode, I found, that this is/was a osx specific behavior. For modern versions of osx it is fixed with: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/56832. Please see the according bug-report: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12956. Technically the accepted answer as well as @jör 's comment are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a duplicate of: [How do I rescue from a `require': no such file to load in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460891/how-do-i-rescue-from-a-require-no-such-file-to-load-in-ruby)

You have to specifically `resque LoadError`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint, but in case of a native extension its not working. I updated my question to also include the LoadError.

Comment: I think this is the correct thing. I have neither of these gems but for me pasting your update code returns:

=> Got LoadError

=> LoadError: cannot load such file -- dotstarsimulator