# How does one handle a custom Puppet fact which depends on a gem module?

Tags: puppet

Let's assume I have defined a custom fact for Puppet which depends on the rbvmomi module.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'pathname'
require_relative 'rbvmomi'
require_relative 'rbvmomi/optimist'
require_relative 'optimist'
require_relative 'vm_tag_utility'

Facter.add('custom_attributes') do
  setcode do
    hostname = Facter.value('hostname')
    VmTagUtility.get_vm_custom_attributes(hostname)
  end
end
```

When Puppet applies on an agent, it encounters this error:

```
Error: Facter: error while resolving custom facts in C:/ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\cache\lib\facter\my_custom_fact.rb: cannot load such file -- C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/lib/facter/rbvmomi
```

This tells me rbvmomi isn't present on the agent, or is not in a path searched by Puppet.

So, what's the best way manage the dependency between a custom fact and any supporting gem module?

Answer (score 0):

> So, what's the best way manage the dependency between a custom fact and any supporting gem module?

You have at least these options:

- avoid depending on any gems outside those included in the Puppet distribution.
- include all needed dependencies in your module's `lib` directory, so that they are synced together with the fact.
- [`rescue` the `LoadError`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2460891/2402272), and provide an alternative version of the fact (maybe a dummy) or no fact at all if it occurs.

  - maybe also have Puppet manage the gem, so that the regular version of the fact is available on the next run

    - this is tricky, because you need to install the gem in Puppet's Ruby, not the system Ruby, if any.

Comment: I'm not sure I can _safely_ include the gem dependency in the module's `lib` - would this not be an invisible hard dependency outside the scope of gem management?

Edit: Didn't mean to submit yet...
I believe I can use `puppet_gem` as the provider with package to go through the option for having puppet management. This, I think, would still facilitate a race condition - the fact would be loaded before the gem is installed - but it should be fine on subsequent runs.

Unfortunately, I don't think we can avoid this dependency without writing some API work of our own duplicating the gem.

Comment: Well no, @JeremySylvis, there would be no race condition.  If you rely on Puppet to install the gem then the fact will *definitely* be loaded before Puppet has a chance to install the gem.  This is why "have Puppet manage the gem" is formatted as a sub-point of "rescue the `LoadError`, and [...]".

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, facts are loaded before classes are applied - the first run, the error would occur because the fact is loaded (attempting to load rbvmomi) before the class installing it is applied. Were you suggesting some other way of having Puppet provide the gem?

Comment: @JeremySylvis, yes, facts are loaded before the manifest is applied, or even built.  That is why there is no race condition.  The fact is *definitely* loaded at the beginning of the run, before the manifest is applied.  You seem to be missing the point, which is that you structure the fact code so that the `LoadError` caused by `rbvmomi` not being available does not prevent the fact (or at least the Ruby code containing it) from being successfully loaded.  That gets you past that point so that Puppet can install the Gem, making the fact available on *subsequent* runs.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, I had missed that. I will give it a try.